# How to find Country lat, long based on Country Name on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, latitude-longitude, powerbi-desktop, custom-function

I'm trying to find the Country lat, long to visualize the Country in the world map on Power BI.

[image]

Please suggest me the procedure to find lat, long on PowerBI or any APIs available from PowerBI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to use any API service to get lat-long

Create bingmapsportal account

Here I'm using Microsoft bing maps API services Go to BingMapsPortal account to SignUP account if you already don’t have 
[image]

After SingUp we have login it will redirect to dashboard

[image]

Generate key
Once we reached dashboard page we have to generate key to use restful api services

[image]
Once keys is ready then refer the document to find the api to get the lat and long based on given country

[image]

We use below give url to get lat and long in xml format

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/india?o=xml&key=AjvYaTSLr8dsu4eqeDt0OigOZ_xuTkdVMUQCDMc0gcDPm
```

Use virtualearth API service to get lat and long of the location
    Once data is available then we have to convert that into tabular form
[image]

Create Invoke Custom function
If we need to get multiple countries' dashboard then we have to write custom invoke functions such as given below and save.
[image]

```
= (location) =>

let
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/"&location&")?o=xml&key=AjvYaTSLr8dsu4eqeDt0OigOZ_xuTkdVMUQCDMc0gcDPmj2m57iWiwasSDZSCoNG")),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Copyright", type text}, {"BrandLogoUri", type text}, {"StatusCode", Int64.Type}, {"StatusDescription", type text}, {"AuthenticationResultCode", type text}, {"TraceId", type text}}),
    ResourceSets = #"Changed Type"{0}[ResourceSets],
    ResourceSet = ResourceSets{0}[ResourceSet],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ResourceSet,{{"EstimatedTotal", Int64.Type}}),
    Resources = #"Changed Type1"{0}[Resources],
    #"Expanded Location" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Resources, "Location", {"Name", "Point", "BoundingBox", "EntityType", "Address", "Confidence", "MatchCode", "GeocodePoint"}, {"Location.Name", "Location.Point", "Location.BoundingBox", "Location.EntityType", "Location.Address", "Location.Confidence", "Location.MatchCode", "Location.GeocodePoint"}),
    #"Location Point" = #"Expanded Location"{0}[Location.Point],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Location Point",{{"Latitude", type number}, {"Longitude", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Use lat long to visualize maps
Use that custom invoke function to get multiple lat long by creating new custom column in table

[image]
Later we have to convert embedded table data to column data

[image]

To show Country and count legend without mouse over we have created custom legend column
Using the below query

**Syntax:**

```
State Count COLUMN = 'Table'[State]&" - "&CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Count]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[State]))
```

[image]
Once data is ready on the table then we have to drag and drop the proper value on location, legend, values.

[image]